# Add custom put method to generated controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `records_controller` generated through the regular generator scaffold_controller. I would like to add custom method, lets call it `share` in order to pass there only one parameter with email address. If email exists in my database I would like to add associated within `id` to `record`.

I added share method to `records_controller`:

```
  def share
    logger.info record_params
    logger.info params
    # check email in db and add id
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

form on show view:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "records", action: "share", method: "put", remote: true) do %>
  <%= label_tag(:user_email, "Share for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:user_email) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Share") %>
<% end %>
```

and rule in *routes*:

```
  put    '/records/:id/share', to: 'records#share'
```

Form renders fine but when I press click I get error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/records/2/share"):
```

Comment: `/records/share/:id` != `/records/:id/share`. Try the latter.

Comment: I made an error in the description. It doesn't change anything.

Comment: Why not just use post and be done with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`form_tag` source code](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag), the parameters you pass to the helper are all considered as `url_for_options` and return a wrong output like this:

```
<form action="/records/2/share?method=put&amp;remote=true" method="post">
```

You need to specify which parameters are `url_for_options` and which are only `options`:

```
<%= form_tag({controller: "records", action: "share"}, method: 'put', remote: true) do %>
```